# Angularjs: Mapping angular filters over arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have an angular filter `translate` which does stuff on strings – doesn’t matter what – and a filter `sort` which sorts stuff alphabetically (as in `orderBy : 'toString()'`).

I now want to print out strings from an array `str` of strings, but sorted according to their translation. That is, I want to make the following html code work:

```
<div ng-repeat="s in strs | translate | sort">{{ s }}</div>
```

It doesn’t work – I assume it’s because `translate` is a filter acting on strings, sort of like having signature *String → String*. But I need it to act on *arrays* of strings, right? Sort of like having signature *[String] → [String]*, right? If that’s true, I need to find a way to map `translate` over arrays, such as `strs`, within that angular expression.

How can I do that or achieve what I want elegantly in the angular way?

*Example*. Say `translate` sends strings `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` to `'z'`, `'y'`, `'x'` respectively. I then want the angular-enhanced html element above to produce an equivalent html output to:

```
<div>c</div> <div>b</div> <div>a</div>
```

Comment: Does putting parens make a difference? `s in (strs | translate | sort)`

Comment: @acbabis No, it doesn’t seem so. (But wouldn’t make much sense if it did, right?). On the other hand, there’s a rather complex example behind this question and I’m bad with fiddling. I only tested this with my complex example, and not with something simple, so I wouldn’t know for sure (because I’m not sure where the error is actually coming from).

Comment: I don't understand why your solution doesn't work (maybe it has something to do with stateless filters...), but you may be able to achieve this with a  filter function : `| orderBy: myFilter()`, and inside your filter function just `return $filter('translate')(string)`

Answer (score 1):

If your translation library doesn't support translation on an array, I would add a new filter to your project for this purpose:

```js
angular.module("mymodule", ["pascalprecht.translate"]);
angular.module("mymodule").config(function($translateProvider) {
  // Set up message keys
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    A: 'Apple',
    B: 'Banana'
  })
}).run(function($translate) {
  // Select language
  $translate.use("en");
})
/**
 * @filter translateArray
 * @description Convert an array of message IDs 
 * to an array of translations using the `$translate` service
 * @param {Array<String>} translationIDs - An array of message keys
 * @returns {Array<String>} - An array of translated strings.
 */
.filter("translateArray", function($translate) {
  return function(translationIDs) {
    return translationIDs.map(function(id) {
      return $translate.instant(id);
    })
  };
}).controller("demoController", function($scope) {
  // Template will translate then sort. Should give:
  // Apple, Banana
  $scope.strs = ["B", "A"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-translate/2.10.0/angular-translate.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="mymodule">
  <div ng-controller="demoController">
    <div ng-repeat="s in (strs | translateArray | orderBy:'toString()')">{{s}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```